# How to test in app purchase without sandbox

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Is there any way i can test in app purchases without sandbox. I want to know what happens for in app purchases that are not reviewed by apple team. I can retrieve it properly on sandbox environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to test the in App purchase without sandbox. You need to create test account for testing.
In order to go live in app store your In-app purchases **must be reviewed by apple**.

Comment: Dear Chandan, Thanks for the reply. My application is already live on store. I want to add a new content on my app which is managed with a server. Now how can i send the in app to the apple review team without making it live on application.

Comment: Add in-app purchase item... and uncheck "ready for sale"... You inApp will not be live until you check "ready for sale" option.

Comment: so if it is cleared for sale and waiting for review, users can purchase the item. Please let me know

Comment: Since you have sent your in-app for review... I think the state will be changed to "ready for sale" once apple approved your app.

Comment: Then how can i make the content available on the application for the apple review team to check it.

Comment: @Chandan, some of my in apps are already live on the application. but i have a feature to add more contents through in app purchase on application without app update. So i am creating an identifier and adding it in to my web service so that my application can use it.

Comment: @Anil, 1.Create new in-app purchase item 2.test the item using the test account which you used previously for testing or create new test account 3.submit the item for apple review after proper testing. Thats it